# Dropping the "Lowest Grade" Problem

Tags: arithmetic, discrete-optimization

Let $A=\{a_1, a_2, ... , a_n\}$ be a set of non-negative real numbers and $B=\{b_1, b_2, ..., b_n\}$ be sets of positive real numbers.

Let $s = \dfrac{ \sum_A a}{\sum_B b} =  \dfrac{a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n}{b_1+b_2+\dots+b_n}$.

What I want to do find $k$ so that

$s_1 = \dfrac{\sum_{A-\{a_k\}} a }{\sum_{B-\{b_k\}} b}$ is the largest.

And more generally, find

$s_p = \dfrac{\sum_{A-\{a_{k_1},a_{k_2},\dots,a_{k_p}\}} a }{\sum_{B-\{b_{k_1},b_{k_2},\dots,b_{k_p}\}} b}$

I'm not exactly sure what this is called, and I tried doing a google search but I wasn't able to find what I am looking for.

And of course, I can do this by exhaustion, but I feel that there should be a smart way to figure this out...

Comment: Unless something is known in advance about the elements of that set, there's not much that can be done.

Comment: @anorton So nothing other than brute force?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by brute force, but yes.  Clearly you want to remove the smallest $p$ elements from $A$ and the largest $p$ elements from $B$.  Thus, you just have to find the biggest/smallest elements of a set.  If you're worried about asymptotic performance for a program, I believe there are linear-time algorithms for finding the least/greatest $p$ elements of a set.

Comment: @anorton:  I think he is deleting matching elements, that the sets are really sequences.

Comment: @RossMillikan,@anorton: Yup, I want to delete matching elements.

Comment: Oh!  In that case, I'm not sure.

Comment: The brute-force solution to this is $O(n^k)$ where $n$ is the number of assignments and $k$ is the number of assignments to drop.  I drop the lowest 3 lab grades, and my poor laptop has been trying to compute my students' final grades for quite some time now.  :)

Comment: Maybe $O(n2^k)$ actually.... either way, it's really slow

Comment: @Him I think you were right the first time. It would be $O\left(\binom{n}{k}\right) \sim O\left(n^k\right)$.

Comment: An easier subproblem might be proving/disproving that the solution to the more general case of removing $p$ grades would be obtained by removing the lowest grade $p$ times. Intuitively, it seems right, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: @VarunVejalla yeah, this would be a ["greedy algorithm"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm), and I don't think it works.  Specifically, $\frac{a+b}{d+e} > \frac{a+c}{d+f}$ does not imply $\frac{a+b+g}{d+e+h} > \frac{a+c+g}{a+f+h}$.  i.e. if we keep adding in grades that minimize the average, it is possible that adding in a future grade will flip a minimum that we found in the past.  A couterexample showing the claim above happens at $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h = 50, 3, 12, 100, 10, 30, 10, 30$.  Actually, you get equality at this combo.  If you move $g$ slightly, you can flip the $>$.

Comment: If it worked, greedy would give an $O(n^2)$ algorithm, which would still be not great, but would certainly be a significant improvement

Comment: That's supposed to be a $d$ in the denominator above....

Comment: Considering the ratio of Actual : Possible scores to delete the scores is more optimized since the final percentage depends on weightage rather than raw scores. That is trivial isn't it?

Comment: @AyaanMaan Neither considering the "raw" score, nor the "percent" score suffices to choose the optimal grades to drop.  Check out the section in [the paper I cite below](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Edakane/droplowest.pdf) concerning the scores of student "Dale".  They illustrate the difficulty of the problem nicely.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Edakane/droplowest.pdf) is a short exposition on the problem, including some pretty good examples of why [greedy algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) or [dynamic programming algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) probably won't work.  The key insight that the authors have is that we can transform this from a "find the maximum" problem to a "find the zero of a function" problem, and that function is, fortunately, pretty easy to evaluate at arbitrary points.  Here's the transformation:

We want a subset $S$ of assignments so that:

$$ \frac{\sum_{i \in S} m_i}{\sum_{i \in S} n_i} = q  \tag 1$$

is maximized, where $m_i$ is the student's score on assignment $i$ and $n_i$ is the maximum possible score.  Rearranging this equation, we get:

$$ \sum_{i \in S} \left(m_i - qn_i\right) = 0 \tag 2$$

The LHS is a linear function of $q$ for any given $S$.  We'll just call that $f(q)$ and set about finding the zeros.  Note that at the value of $q_{opt}$ for which equation $(1)$ is maximized, any $S$ but the optimal one give the LHS $< q_{opt}$.  This translates to the LHS $< 0$ in equation $(2)$.  Let's create a new function:

$$F(q) = \text{max}_S \left(\sum_{i \in S} \left(m_i - qn_i\right), |S|=n-k\right)$$

$F$ is piecewise linear, continuous, and, since all of the pieces have negative slope ($-\sum n_i$), then it is monotonic.  This means it has exactly one zero.  We know from before that that zero is $q_{opt}$, and it occurs during the "piece" where we're using the optimal subset.  The magic of $F$ is that it is easy to evaluate at any given $q$ (just choose the largest $|S|$ $m_i - qn_i$ terms).  So, we can use arbitrary zero-finding mechanisms to find $q_{opt}$ and, as a corollary, $S$.

The paper I reference above suggests the bisection algorithm and Newton's method.  In my experiments, and also, according to them, in their experiments, Newton's method works pretty well.  However, it seems to me that $F$ may have up to (but generally has fewer than) $n\choose k$ "pieces".  This means that we might well end up doing $n\choose k$ iterations of Newton's method in the worst case.  The bisection algorithm is actually potentially worse, since we can presumably make the $q_{opt}$ "piece" arbitrarily small, and therefore arbitrarily difficult to find with the bisection algorithm.  So, this method is arguably not better than the brute-force algorithm in the worst case.  I do not have any examples of what that worst case may be.

## TL; DR

The Newton's method solution seems to be worst-case $O ({n \choose k})$.  Possibly, it has a better average case.  Certainly, in the situations I've used it, it is *way* faster than the naïve brute force solution.

Here's python code implementing the Newton's Method solution:

```
import heapq
def assignment_subset_zero(q, k_drop, scores, points_possible):
    f = scores - q*points_possible
    S = heapq.nlargest(f.shape[0] - k_drop, range(f.shape[0]), key = f.take)
    return np.sum(scores[S])/np.sum(points_possible[S]), S

# find the subset of assignments to optimize the weighted average grade
# scores and points_possible should be equal-length numpy arrays
def optimal_assignment_subset(k_drop, scores, points_possible):
    previous_q = -1
    this_q = 0
    while previous_q != this_q:
        #print(previous_q, this_q)
        previous_q = this_q
        this_q, S = assignment_subset_zero(previous_q, k_drop, scores, points_possible)
    return S
```

And some code to run the more interesting examples included in the paper:

```
def dales_quiz_test_set(c, b):
    return (
        np.array([20+c] + [20 + i - b for i in range(1,11)]),
        np.array([40 + i*2 for i in range(11)])
    )

def set_equal(s1, s2):
    return (len(s1) == len(s2)) and (len(s1 & s2) == len(s1))

assert set_equal(set(optimal_assignment_subset(5, *dales_quiz_test_set(4,1))), {0,10,9,8,7,6})
assert set_equal(set(optimal_assignment_subset(5, *dales_quiz_test_set(6,1))), {0,1,2,3,4,5})
```

Answer (score 1):

The naive thing is to delete the smallest $\frac {a_i}{b_i}$, but this fails.  Let $A=(1,51,100), B=(2,100,100).$  The worst grade is $\frac 12$, but deleting it leaves $\frac {151}{200}$, while deleting the $\frac {51}{100}$ leaves $\frac {101}{102}$, much better.  The simple approach is to scale the tests to the same possible score, then it is easy.

Comment: Hmm... it appears dropping the $k$ with the largest $b_k - a_k$ seems to do the trick.

Comment: I don't think that works, either.  Let $A=(1,2,100), B=(2,4,103)$.  At the start you have $\frac {103}{109}$, but dropping the last leaves you with $\frac 36$

Comment: ::forehead slap:: you are right. I was thinking about minimizing the difference between the numerator and the denominator, but of course that doesn't imply a bigger fraction.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem via mixed integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $x_j$ indicate whether you keep exam $j$ or not.  The problem is to maximize
$$\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n a_j x_j}{\sum_{j=1}^n b_j x_j} \tag1$$
subject to $$\sum_{j=1}^n x_j = n - p \tag2$$
You can linearize the objective $(1)$ by introducing nonnegative decision variables $z$ and $y_j$ and the following linear constraints:
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n a_j x_j &= \sum_{j=1}^n b_j y_j \tag3 \\
y_j &\le x_j &&\text{for all $j$} \tag4 \\
y_j &\le z &&\text{for all $j$} \tag5 \\
y_j &\ge z - (1-x_j) &&\text{for all $j$} \tag6 \\
\end{align}
The idea is that $y_j = z\cdot x_j$.
Now maximize $z$ subject to $(2)$-$(6)$.

Comment: Using some integer linear programming solution algorithm, can we use this representation of the problem to find a more tractable solution?  A lot of the magic of turning a problem into a linear programming problem comes from being able to efficiently solve the dual, but IIRC duality is much more nuanced with integer problems.

Comment: These problems solve very quickly with the traditional branch-and-bound algorithm.